# win10 cloning to bigger hardisk results in unusable recovery partition

Tags: windows-10, disk-cloning, recovery

does anybody know what could have happened:

after cloning win10 HDD (with clonezilla) to bigger HDD everything went fine, able to start win10 on new bigger HDD with no problems, but recovery partition (think talking about window recovery enviroment) prompted to an error like picture below:

[image]

I played little bit with `reagentc /disable` and `reagentc /enable` and `reagentc /info` and `bcdedit /enum all` showed normal results.

Ended up having to reinstall from recovery media. Any idea about what could have happened ??

Edit after cloning I moved the recovery partition further down to increase the size of win partition to take advantage of bigger HDD (used GParted)

partition were like:

[image]

boot like:

[image]

Comment: [edit] your question to explain how you cloned your HDD exactly. Are you looking to solve this error or just understand the reason it happened, without logs and ability to diagnose the issue, explaining what happen will be nearly impossible.

Comment: @Ramhound, its just curiosity I had to reinstall everything from recovery media. Cloned with Clonezzilla, and windows strarted all right, hidden recovery partition was there (right size) but was getting error ?? Is it normal behaviour ?? everything looked OK from here: https://www.ubackup.com/windows-10/windows-10-recovery-environment-missing-5740.html

Comment: So for example if I asked you what the layout of the partitions were would you be able to provide that information, the partition layout of the clone,  or of the original drive.

Comment: think recovery was after win10 @Ramhound added to question and were identical (in term of sequence, just different size of win10 )

Comment: The screenshot is from the original drive or the clone? I am not seeing the partitions I would expect from a bootable drive

Comment: pc was from friend of mine, reinstalled and gave it back, pictures are like it. Asking because I am wondering about what happened @Ramhound